# Accessing controls from different forms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a main form with some buttons, textboxes, labels, etc.
On a second form I would like to copy the text from the main forms textbox onto the second form.

Have tried:

```
var form = new MainScreen();
TextBox tb= form.Controls["textboxMain"] as TextBox;
textboxSecond.Text = tb.Text;
```

But it just causes an exception. The main screen textbox is initialised and contains text.
When I hover over `form` I can see all the controls are there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the Exception it raises?

Comment: The controls that you create by designer are private by default.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan What does this change? OP tries to access it as `form.Controls["textboxMain"]`

Comment: And you are creating a new `MainScreen` when you most likely want to use the existing instance of your form.

Comment: what is the and where is it declared `textboxSecond.Text = tb.Text;` looks like this is the line that's causing the error can't tell without seeing the exact exception

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` basically it doesn't know what `tb` is. It is `null`.

Comment: You did not give your `TextBox` the name of tb you gave it textbox

Comment: sorry that was a typo, updated question above. In my actual code I have it the same name and still the same error

Comment: So we are not looking at the real code.  **Never** do that, always copy/paste code into a question.  High odds that your string is just wrong, few reasons to set this textbox's Name property to "textboxMain".  It is already in something called "main" so no point in repeating it.  Creating a new instance of MainScreen is quite wrong as well.

Comment: Are you creating the SecondForm in your MainScreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the original code, there are two potential reasons for the `NullReferenceException` you are getting. First, `tb` is not defined in the code you provide so I am not sure what that is.

Secondly, `TextBox textbox = form.Controls["textboxMain"] as TextBox` can return `null` if the control is not found *or* is not a `TextBox`. Controls, by default, are marked with the `private` accessor, which leads me to suspect that `form.Controls[...]` will return `null` for `private` members.

While marking the controls as `internal` will potentially fix this issue, it's really not the best way to tackle this situation and will only lead to poor coding habits in the future. `private` accessors on controls are perfectly fine.

A better way to share the data between the forms would be with `public` properties. For example, let's say you have a `TextBox` on your main screen called `usernameTextBox` and want to expose it publicly to other forms:

```
public string Username
{
  get { return usernameTextBox.Text; }
  set { usernameTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

Then all you would have to do in your code is:

```
var form = new MainForm();
myTextBox.Text = form.Username; // Get the username TextBox value
form.Username = myTextBox.Text; // Set the username TextBox value
```

The great part about this solution is that you have better control of how data is stored via properties. Your `get` and `set` actions can contain logic, set multiple values, perform validation, and various other functionality.

If you are using *WPF* I would recommend looking up the *MVVM* pattern as it allows you to do similar with object states.

Comment: Yes, creating the second form from the first works just fine as you mentioned above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PhoenixReborn is correct. The problem is that you are creating a new MainScreen, which means that new controls are created, so unless the text in your controls are initialized in the form constructor, they are going to be empty. Usually, the way to handle this is to pass the first form instance to the second form, like this:

```
SecondForm second = new SecondForm(this);
```

and in the second form:

```
public SecondForm (MainForm form)
{
    // do something with form, like save it to a property or access it's controls
}
```

That way, the second form will have access to the first form's controls. You might consider making the properties you need to use public (in the designer properties pane). That way you can just do `form.textboxMain.Text`.