# Access and modify form listbox from another class

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm having some issues accessing and modifying a listbox control from another class.

Here's the MainForm, which holds the listbox:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private static MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

    internal static MainForm init()
    {
        return MainForm.mainForm;
    }

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And here's the second class that I'm using to attempt to modify the listbox (the items are added from an event):

```
public class Utils
{
    void ItemsReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs<ListboxItems> e)
    {
        MainForm.init().listBox1.Items.Add("test");
    }
}
```

Using this code setup, nothing is added to the listbox. Any ideas? Or even a better way to tackle this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing controls from different forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296690/accessing-controls-from-different-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Typically visual studio generates the following code in a `Program.cs` file:

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

If this line still exists, your static `mainForm` variable will hold a *different* instance of `MainForm` than the one visible when running the application. If I'm right, change the line in `Program.cs` to:

```
Application.Run(MainForm.init());
```

On a side note, while using the singleton (anti)pattern, consider changing the name of that method to `GetInstance()` because `init()` appears to initialize something.